# How to make a custom search input reusable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

In my application, one of the most used elements is the search input, which makes it possible to search for products, topics, categories, etc.

I have already created the search input element, see below.

How to make the navbar search input reusable so that I can use it in other places?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, FormControl, InputBase } from '@mui/material'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ContainedButton } from '../../ui-kit';

const StyledInput = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: 'inherit',
    border: 'none',
    outline: 'none',
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
        maxHeight: '30px',
        padding: '4px 16px',
        maxWidth: '100%',
        borderLeft: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[100]}`,
        fontSize: 16,
        lineHeight: 1.125,
        color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    },
    width: '100%',
}));

const CONTAINED_BUTTON_STYLED = {
    minWidth: '111px',
    borderRadius: '0 2px 2px 0',
};

export const SearchInput = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <FormControl sx={{ flexDirection: 'row', ml: '16px', width: '100%' }}>
                <StyledInput placeholder="Search on Website" />
                <ContainedButton sx={CONTAINED_BUTTON_STYLED} title="Search" />
            </FormControl>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply expose all of the `InputBase` props as props of your custom `SearchInput` component, so that you maintain the same full API, and apply these props on the underlying `InputBase` component (possibly styled), typically using the [JSX spread attributes syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes):

> If you already have `props` as an object, and you want to pass it in JSX, you can use `...` as a “spread” syntax to pass the whole props object.

```
export const SearchInput = (props: React.ComponentProps<typeof InputBase>) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <FormControl sx={{ flexDirection: 'row', ml: '16px', width: '100%' }}>
                <StyledInput placeholder="Search on Website" {...props} />
                <Button sx={CONTAINED_BUTTON_STYLED} title="Search" />
            </FormControl>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Then you can use it as a "normal" `InputBase`:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    return (
        <SearchInput value="hello" onChange={(event) => console.log(event)} />
    )
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=37&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAIQgA8AaOAMWhAGEIA7GHABtWASV5gArjDooAzklZ0pMPnAC+cbLgIABEBOAB6EChhIowFILIVo8WrJgBPQUgAm6zTjz49B46bmloKGji5IsvgA3KSkaHyOcADKzq5uYpLwALxwYWkAFBlSMvIAlPn5tDAAFkggSOqlcFkAfHCVpHBdcPGC0ABcBMC8tRYw+Myd3QBG0G7mg-i8fEgTU10QUoLDSIvLvKuT3QQAZHAAdACyBkXSckgAtMOZ+IPU68dwJowAEkjAAHNqjBFgBmAAMYEYa0+3TAKDcbmGAMWABYoXAAIwANihMNhXxQjAA6sA3DVFpjweCAKT42GzKDzKAAGSQmBBcAABpiMbIINsPAASag1OpIc7w1wwMznAFEJwAbSp4IAumouUcCZg+DAksAAF67LHYrWw7YHP6A4GDTHnTEAJgArGbPr0BnAxfVJVYkDKJWZGDBJRYTFAnK61K6AO5kikEFV0yZqUqlGJxBLwLgAeQAcgAVACCIlzAFEACIAfToAFV8-m85WkvmAJosivNGgfEDDUnk6qUzG86GuxnMhAI4ASWSLcFwB0YheMODgtZqdNIRiUeDxXiJJKoKBoaq3Tv5MA4MAzxDEYM8cArfgABUvsgAPM4wEgIJg4LcSkgLRNK0XbHEQMASFAvDtB8xxvgwjAtLBBJvhwUDcLqQi5IwWTULQmCuIw5bAEQGDAHwiw4NGExfIIlK4iOcCxv2lLUnS6hqEhBLcXAb4pOE6TiFIcBgII6BINUArMlkABEB4oEe1RwKoxJINMsjAGYMk0OcukXhAV4aIYXE8bC8HKKosg4dQOYFsWZZVrW9aNs2bYVhoMCaa4snyYp2nGchZmGGhGH8EIJlBQhEVwKUpBqLEmASLwZGqE+ClIPw96QAc-D5E07xgX6kHQfkgW8b5x6ngAblYEhILJtSCH02l8Fw1QoLwAL1dQ+RIFVGUwMBbS7vyrjnH0AK9f1-ClEZ0WxWoQA)

Comment: Wow, that's nice, it was useful and solved my problem.